# How to find datetime's on postgres linked server greater than datetime2 on local SQL Server using Open Query

Tags: postgresql, linked-server, openquery

I'm trying to identify new data on a postgres database that does not yet exist on our local SQL Server 2017 so I can download the new data onto our SQL Server. To identify this, I'm connecting to the postgres db using a linked server and then using openquery.

I've inserted the MAX datetime2(7) from our local SQL "events" table into a temp table called #latest:

`CREATE TABLE #latest (latest DATETIME2(7))`

| latest |
| --- |
| 2023-01-26 14:40:19.1470000 |

There is a "time" column within the "event" table in the linked server with a datatype of timestamp with time zone. Running this code returns successfully:

```
    DECLARE @Query          NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT
        @Query = '
        SELECT
            [time],[eventID]
        FROM OPENQUERY(
        [PostgresServer]
        ,''
            select 
                "time",
                "eventID"
            from "event" t 
            limit 1
        ''
        )' 
    FROM #latest

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
```

| time | eventID |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-11-17 11:05:17.2450000 | 730d544e-de4b-47a7-b8d0-80742dc4240d |

However, when I try to add a where clause, I get an error:

```
    DECLARE @Query          NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT
        @Query = '
        SELECT
            [time],[eventID]
        FROM OPENQUERY(
        [PostgresServer]
        ,''
            select 
                "time",
                "eventID"
            from "event" t 
            where "time" > '[latest]'
            limit 1
        ''
        )' 
    FROM #latest

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
> Incorrect syntax near 'latest'.

I added + to each side of [latest] but then I started getting operator errors:

> The data types varchar and datetime2 are incompatible in the add operator.

So I've ended up with the below:

`where "time" > '+CAST([latest] AS NVARCHAR(100))+'`

But I get this error:

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "PostgresServer" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.

> Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 22
> Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "PostgresServer".

Is there a better way I can identify new data on the linked server? Or fix the error?!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the answer here: [SQL Server : use datetime variable in openquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519572/sql-server-use-datetime-variable-in-openquery)

needed to add a varchar variable instead of using the datetime column in my temp table :)